# Remove Old Permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a Wordpress website.  I have changed my permalinks several times.  All past versions of the permalinks I used are still working.  If I type them into the URL bar, I am taken to the page WITHOUT the URL changing/redirecting to the new/current permalink.

Why aren't the old permalinks redirecting to the new one?

This is causing issues with Google reading duplicate content.

```
Example: .com/lightbulb .com/shop/lightbulb
```

The second URL is old, but still works when I type it in.

Shouldn't it redirect to the new one? 
How can I remove old permalinks from being found by Google?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.exapmle.com/lightbulb/$1 [R=301,L]    please check this and let me know ?

Comment: I came to this quora question, with a different requirement. A slug was edited and I want to make the old slug now available for use. wordpress was giving a 301, but I wanted to remove that. Finally I found this article https://wptheming.com/2015/12/purge-old-slug-redirects/ to solve my problem. Posting it here hoping it would be helpful for someone coming here with that requirement.

Answer (score 4):

I think the old permalinks is stored in the table `postmeta` with the `meta_key` of `_wp_old_slug`

If you wanted to clear all of the old slugs you could use this:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug';
```

Comment: If he doesn't determine why is this happening, are entries in wp_postmeta duplicated or not, I would suggest not to delete but to update table by replacing old links with new ones. Also, is table prefix "wp_"?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how `_wp_old_slug` can cause the problem?

Comment: In case user reaches the post by the old slug, WP redirects to the post by reading the `_wp_old_slug` meta value. It serves the similar purpose like 301 redirect.

Comment: I know but why old links didn't redirect to new links? As OP said: ***All past versions of the permalinks I used are still working...WITHOUT the URL changing/redirecting to the new/current permalink***.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, Wordpress doesn't handle redirections when you change your permalinks structure. There is 2 ways to handle this, through:

1. **The htaccess rewriting rules** (manually editing the .htaccess file) depending on your new old/new permalinks structure. 
   If `.com/lightbulb` is the new path and `.com/shop/lightbul` the old one:

```css
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RedirectMatch 301 /shop/lightbulb(.*) /lightbulb$1
  # or
  # RewriteRule ^shop/lightbulb?(.*) http://www.domain.com/lightbulb$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But if you want to redirect old permalink structure `.com/shop/` to main domain your `.htaccess` rules will be:

```css
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RedirectMatch 301 /shop/(.*) /$1
  # or
  # RewriteRule ^shop/?(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 
</IfModule>
```

> Permanent redirection is used for best SEO practices, redirecting **definitively** old permalinks to new ones, avoiding duplicate content, and telling search engines that your old permalinks have been moved **definitively** to new ones.

2. **Redirection Wordpress free plugins** *(there is a lot)*:

   - [**Redirections**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin is the most popular and offer a easy-to-manage 301 redirections and 404 error tracking. It also offers more advanced tools to help you keep track of loose ends on your site like broken links and orphan pages.
   - [**Simple 301 redirects**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) plugin is simple and deals with 301 redirect creation for when you’ve permanently moved content from one location to another.
   - [**Quick Page/Post Redirect**](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) plugin easily redirect pages/posts or custom post types to another page/post or external URL by specifying the redirect URL and type (301, 302, 307, meta).
   - [**Safe Redirect Manager**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/) plugin comes with an additional whitelist feature for added security…
   - [**SEO Redirection Plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-redirection/) plugin offers support for generating 301, 302, and 307 redirects and also supports 404 error monitoring with easy one-click redirection…

---

**Converting old path *(urls)* in database** *(if they still exist)*:

> You can use [**Search and Replace**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) free plugin, to easily find some old related urls or path in your database and bulk replace them by the new ones. This is a very powerful plugin, a little buggy, but working fine when you know it *(but make **always** a **backup** before)*.

A recent reference: 
[A Simple Guide to Changing Your Permalinks Without Breaking Your WordPress Website](http://www.wpexplorer.com/change-permalinks-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

> Why aren't the old permalinks redirecting to the new one?

Each time you add new permalink structure and flush rewrite rules, WordPress doesn't redirect old links to new links. Instead, WordPress will alter the old links with the new links completely.

> All past versions of the permalinks I used are still working.

In WordPress, a URL doesn't map to route. It's [looped through rewrite rules to find a match](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-query-overview-how-a-page-request-is-translated-to-a-mysql-query/) - a real URL which can be translated into database queries by [parse_request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/parse_request/) method.

It means that if the old rewrite rules which match old links aren't removed. The old links still work.

> How can I remove old permalinks from being found by Google?

Since they have been indexed by Google, I think [permanent redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) is the best solution.

I assume you're using Apache, if not, please let me know.

In your case, just add following code before WordPress rules in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^shop/(.+)/?$" "http://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where does the old permlink store?It be stored in some database?Why can't be selected and deleted it from the database?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature The rewrite rules added via `init` hook are not saved in database. Or it might be cached as well. Base on the info of the current question, it hard to know what is problem. My answer is just some guidelines to help you find out the problem but I hope it can help :)

Comment: Remove default routes instructions - https://wpreset.com/remove-default-wordpress-rewrite-rules-permalinks/. Still make sure you're redirecting if Google has already indexed.