# How do I delete the old Custom Post Type permalink after rewriting the URL to exclude the slug?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a `Custom Post Type` called Book, and the link is: `mywebsite.com/book/mybookname`

I want to change this so that the link is `mywebsite.com/mybookname`.

I have added the following code to change the link and it works as expected:

```
function books_theme_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'book' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'books_theme_remove_slug', 10, 3 );

function books_theme_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'book', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'books_theme_parse_request' );
```

The problem is that the old link(`mywebsite.com/book/mybookname`) is still working. I'd like to make that link go to a 404 page without breaking the current links.

I tried the following but it breaks everything:

```
function books_theme_parse_request( $query ) {
    if(isset($query->query['post_type']) && $query->query['post_type'] == 'book'){
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
    }

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'book', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'books_theme_parse_request' );
```

How do I delete old url?

Comment: Not sure this matters but why are you using the Spanish word for book->libro when based on your other code your are using the English word for your post type?

Comment: where did you put the code you tried? i guess there are more conditions that should be added, like to know if this is the admin or public part of the site, the type of page, etc. By the way, how did it break everything? erro codes?

Comment: fjoe: Its a spanish website, I used book here because I think its easier to get help if english speakers can undrstand it easily, I edited it.

Kaddath, the code I tried is in books_theme_parse_request( $query ). ill edit my post to make it clearer. It brakes it because everywhere where a book is displayed it turns into a 404 error. I only want the single of book with the original url to be 404

Comment: Could be a few things (1) I presume you've re-saved permalinks? (2) Have you any caching plugins installed? (3) WP creates a new redirects every time you change slugs, so its possible there are old redirects keeping the old link alive, so you could try the following [Remove Old Permalinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409265/remove-old-permalinks). Also see: [Does WordPress keep track of a post's URL history and provide automatic redirects?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33361/does-wordpress-keep-track-of-a-posts-url-history-and-provide-automatic-redirect)

Comment: you can try to replace your conditions to your 404 test by this, to limit to public part and single post pages (is_singular with a parameter checks also if the post type corresponds): `if(!is_admin() && is_singular( 'book' ))`. But that probably won't be enough, because i think single book posts will also be blocked with the short url. That's a start anyway

Comment: This shouldn't be happening in the first place, so you shouldn't add a to your code to fix it. Instead, **find the source of the problem and fix *it*** - otherwise you could introduce all sorts of problems down the line.

Comment: Kaddath. is_singular( 'book' ) gives me true in both /book/nameofthebook and /nameofthebook.

Fluffy you're right, can you point me in the right direction of my problem? I want my post type Book urls to be website.com/post-title not website.com/slug/post-title. If you know a way to do this that is not the one I posted and that solves my problem I would be thrilled

Comment: yes that's what i thought when i said it won't be enough. But i'm not sure that changing the way the links are generated for this type affects also the fact that the old url cannot be used anymore. In many frameworks, posts are accessible via multiple urls, that's why they declare a canonical one. (edit: there are options in admin for that if i remember, but i have no wp site to test at the moment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't be happening in the first place, so you shouldn't try to fix it programmatically - instead you should fix it at source. Try to identify the cause and fix it. Otherwise you could introduce other issues down the line.

Some possible solutions, depending on the cause:

1. **Flush your Rewrite Cache**
   Wordpress doesn't write redirections into the .htaccess, it uses [rewrite rules](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-query-overview-how-a-page-request-is-translated-to-a-mysql-query/?ptma=b&utm_expid=3606929-109.P6e7JvhjTrWFxwrJZjRkog.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F32409265%2Fremove-old-permalinks) to parse the url and find a match for the redirection.
   It means that if you don't refresh your rewrite rules, the old links still work.
   *Ref: [SarahCoding's answer to 'Remove Old Permalinks?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409265/remove-old-permalinks#answer-37958123)*
    
   ***How to do it:***
    **Re-saving your permalinks** will flush the rewrite rules, but there if that doesn't work there are [Three Ways to Flush the Rewrite Cache in WordPress](https://www.webhostinghero.com/3-ways-to-flush-the-rewrite-cache-in-wordpress/)
2. **Clear your Cache**
   If you have an Caching plugins installed, they will need to be cleared. Some security plugins also use caching e.g. Securi. It could also just be cached in your browser.
    
   ***How to do it:*** 
   See [How to Clear Your Cache in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-clear-your-cache-in-wordpress/)
3. **Delete old WP permalinks**
   When you update a slug, the old permalinks are still stored in the database. This could cause issues if you want to use a slug that you had previously used for example.
    
    
   ***How to do it:*** 
   The old permalinks are stored in the table `postmeta` with the `meta_key` of `_wp_old_slug`. To clear all of the old slugs, run this query in your WP database:

   `DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug';`

    
   *Ref [Mark Dave Tumanda's answer to 'Remove Old Permalinks?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409265/remove-old-permalinks#answer-37958123)*
4. **Check Redirection Plugins**
   If you are using any redirection plugins, check the redirection rules in case there is anything there that is clashing with your new urls.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment all you need then is to know if the url contains /book ... see below for the added snip-it:

```
function books_theme_parse_request( $query ) {
    global $wp;
    $current_url =  home_url( $wp->request );

    if (strpos($current_url, "/book" == false)) { return; }

    if(isset($query->query['post_type']) && $query->query['post_type'] == 'book'){
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
    }

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'book', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'books_theme_parse_request' );
```

As people have mentioned [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#A_Warning_About_Admin_Usage)

A Warning About Admin Usage

This filter can also be used to affect admin screen queries. Be sure to check if your modification is affecting your post edit screens. For example, just checking is_main_query() and is_post_type_archive('movie') will also change the query for the edit.php?post_type=movie admin screen, unless you also check for !is_admin()