# Wordpress adds -2 to my post slug

Tags: wordpress, numbers, duplicates, slug

Wordpress adds a -2 to my post slug. I know this can be caused by a post or attachment with the same name. It's a brand new blog with just 3 posts and 3 attachments, I could have checked for duplicates manually but used tools and a query just in case, to delete revisions, etc.

I used plugins Optimize Database after Deleting Revisions, Find Dupicates and Media Deduper, and it didn't work.
Plus I seached for duplicates on phmMyAdmin with query:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, a.post_type, a.post_status
FROM wp_posts AS a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'post'
AND post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY post_title
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'post'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
```

And found no duplicates.
FYI I'm using plugins:
Akismet, Code Snippets, Genesis Simple Edits, Jetpack, and the ones mentioned above for database cleaning.

Any ideas on what I need to do to fix this issue?
I look forward to your replies. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Have you emptied all trash, cleared your cache and resaved your permalinks?

Comment: does this happen to all posts?

Comment: I have emptied all trash. I cleared my browsers' cache (you refer to that cache right?), tested in IE, Chrome, FF. It didn't happen to posts #1 and #2, it started happening with post #3, I added some other test posts and yes now it happens to all new posts.

Comment: FYI, I'm using a number to title my posts, so titles are "1" , "2" and so on. I found a discussion on this practice here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/481/can-i-use-a-number-for-a-post-page-slug , some people say it works some say it doesn't. I wanted to mention this just in case it helps. Thanks!

Comment: I actually means Wordpress cache - see here for [How to delete the old Custom Post Type permalink after rewriting the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896666/how-do-i-delete-the-old-custom-post-type-permalink-after-rewriting-the-url-to-ex/45897149#45897149) - the same processes apply. But if its happening for all posts and you are using numbers as the slug, then that's the most likely cause - as you mention, WP has problems with all-numeric slugs.

Comment: Well, I reinstalled WP up from the ground and now using non-numeric titles for posts. No problems so far. It seems the numbers were causing trouble. Thanks for your help.