# Wordpress: the category page display a 404 error when I change the Permalink settings

Tags: wordpress, url, post, categories, permalinks

Each post of my wordpress blog is in a category and I added a Categories widget in my blog. I changed my permalink settings from Plain to Post Name. Now I have an issue:

- When I configure my permalink with post name to have friendly URL the page that displays all the posts of a category or when I go to myblog/category/name-category, I have a 404 error. But when I have plain permalinks, each category page display all the posts.

Take an example of what I would like. If I have a category Typing and I put the posts: Post1 and Post4 in this category. I would like to have a page Typing where I can see a list with Post1 and Post4.

Is it because the id can't be translate in friendly URL for the category? Someone know how to configure properly wordpress to display these pages?

Comment: Take a look at this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896666/how-do-i-delete-the-old-custom-post-type-permalink-after-rewriting-the-url-to-ex/45897149#45897149 The question was about deleting permalinks, but you would still use the same process to flush rewrite rules & cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, some permalink plugins blocked the Post Name permalinks settings so I deactivated them and the category pages are working.