# Wordpress How can I remove redirect?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wordpress-rest-api

example:

https://www.ozgurbilgi.net/etiketler/aysegul-tecimer (no such link)

to https://www.ozgurbilgi.net/aysegul-tecimer-ustsuz-danscilar

I tried this

```
function remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink( $redirect_url ) {
    if ( is_404() && !isset($_GET['p']) )
        return false;
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink' );
```

I tried this

```
DELETE FROM <code>wp_postmeta</code> WHERE <code>meta_key</code> = '_wp_old_slug'
```

but these did not solve the problem.

my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I searched for it in the database but I couldn’t find it. I do not understand how it redirect.  How can I cancel this redirect? thanks

Comment: Check this answer to see how to clear old slugs from redirecting: [How do I delete the old Custom Post Type permalink after rewriting the URL to exclude the slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896666/how-do-i-delete-the-old-custom-post-type-permalink-after-rewriting-the-url-to-ex/45897149#45897149)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I already said I was doing this.

Comment: "*I already said I was doing this*" You already said you were doing *one* of those steps (no. 3 in the list). There are 3 others and they are all to do with caching which you didn't mention and is more likely the root of the problem.

Comment: @FluffyKitten The problem is related to the structure of the wordpress.I tried it with the new wordpress.   I can stop guessing for the normal link but if it gets the prefix (etiketler like this) , the guessing cannot be stopped.