# Wordpress automatically created a redirect that I need removed

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301, permalinks

I made an edit to a page on a Wordpress site that included changing its parent. Unfortunately I was not paying attention and this move somehow changed the permalink/slug which I saved before noticing. In addition Wordpress automatically created a 301 redirect to go from the original URL to this new URL. I went back in and changed the permalink/slug back to the original but that redirect still stands so it stills sends the page to the new url it created rather than keeping it to updated option (updated meaning me typing in the original slug).

I am looking for a way to remove the 301 redirect, but do not know where to start.

The original URL: https://www.synergex.com/rev11

The newly generated URL: https://www.synergex.com/products/synergy-de-rev11-licensing-faq

I also tried simply creating a brand new page using the original slug/permalink /rev11 but it gets changed to /rev11-2 so it seems like it it must remember the /rev11 somewhere.

I am hoping there is a way to do this through the WP Dashboard and am open to suggestions. This site does have the Redirection plugin installed but I've checked through the lists and this redirect was not created or listed in it. I also tried to add a redirect to do the opposite (redirect from the new URL to old) but of course it just created a loop that timed out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete the old Custom Post Type permalink after rewriting the URL to exclude the slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896666/how-do-i-delete-the-old-custom-post-type-permalink-after-rewriting-the-url-to-ex)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1.2:** You probably have a problem with your old permalinks not getting flushed properly. But do not worry the great people at Wordpress got a function for that called `flush_rewrite_rules();`

> Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules. This function is
> useful when used with custom post types as it allows for automatic
> flushing of the WordPress rewrite rules (usually needs to be done
> manually for new custom post types). However, this is an expensive
> operation so it should only be used when necessary.

*Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/*

Add the following to the top of your `function.php`:

```
<?php
/**
* Removes a function from a specified filter hook.
* More about flush_rewrite_rules(); @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/
*/
flush_rewrite_rules();

/*
* Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules.
* More about remove_filter(); @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/
*/
remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm sorry I don't know much about php so could be missing something obvious here. But I did add that to the top of my function.php and nothing changed. Do I need to add more than just that function call?

Comment: Please define what you mean by `I made an edit to a page on a Wordpress site that included changing its parent.` ?

Comment: Sure, so there is a page attributes box in the WP editor. In there it has the option to choose a Parent page, by default it's (No Parent), a template, and order. Previously this page had no parent, and then it was moved to use a Product page as its parent. This is a link to a screenshot of what I am talking about: https://en-support.files.wordpress.com/2019/03/page-attributes-option.png?w=640

Comment: So now it has a parent page? And the parent page is "product"? Ord did you remove the parent page but the permalink didn't update ? If so, does any other page suffer from the same problem?

Comment: I moved it so that it had a parent page "Products" I think that is was triggered adding that piece to the permalink. After discovering that I removed the parents page hoping that would help fix the issue but it did not. As far as I know, there isn't an issue of a 301 redirect on any other pages.

I also tried simply creating a brand new page using the same /rev11 slug but it keeps adding a -2 to the end of it, meaning /rev11-2 which tells me it thinks there is another page using /rev11 or it's still hooked into the original page with the redirect

Comment: `As far as I know, there isn't an issue of a 301 redirect on any other pages.` This is Wordpress default behaviour, to avoid 404 errors.

Comment: Yes, I've picked up on that default behavior through this issue, however there must be a way that I can go back to the previous slug and stop the redirect right? That is what I am trying to do. I want the original, shorter slug for this page, not the longer one that was accidentally created. But I can't go back to the original because even when I do it still tries to redirect to the longer version.

Comment: Did you look at the page permalink? What does it look like? You can see it on the page itself on the right side menu

Comment: Yes, that is what has been changed. Originally it was /rev11 then it was changed to products/synergy-de-rev11-licensing-faq. So I tried typing in /rev11 to replace that long one but it still redirects to the long one.

Comment: Can you try adding this line on top of the previous one I gave you `remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');`, then delete the page (if you can) and recreate it. You should alse purge all caches

Comment: I added that as well, though prefer not to completely delete the page has it has some revision history I'd like to keep. Nothing happened, though I am now at /rev11-3 as an autocorrection for the slug name. Is there way to remove previous slug names that are no long used? I tried the Remove Old Slug plugin but it didn't even detect that there were past slugs with /rev11

Comment: Ok, for some reason your slug still exist in the database, I've just found an other related question with a detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896666/how-do-i-delete-the-old-custom-post-type-permalink-after-rewriting-the-url-to-ex, I've flagged your question as a duplicate.