# Wordpress new page redirects to old 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have this strange problem in Wordpress. If I create a page such as `Lead` with a slug `lead` and therefore url http://example.com/lead. If I enter the url `http://example.com/lead` into the browser it ends up being redirected to `http://example.com/learning/program/lead`

I have tried to disable wordpress automatic redirection feature with;

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

But that does not seem to work. Even when both pages don't exist I end up with; `http://example.com/learning/program/lead`

Comment: Maybe there was a 301 redirect rule? Try to access the "/lead" page in Incognito mode or clear your cache prior for trying.

Comment: No, It does not look like it. I have looked at the rewrite rules and there is nothing that could redirect a url like that.

Comment: Try to save Permalinks again?

Comment: I have. But the problem is still there.

Comment: Do you have a category or taxonomy term called lead? Or did you have an old page that you deleted that had the slug "lead"?

Comment: Yes, I did have an old page that I deleted that had the slug lead

Comment: Have you completely deleted this page? please notice that after deleting it, the post goest to "Trash" but still exists. Consider removing it completely and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed any redirect plugin and set redirection otherwise 301 redirect.

Comment: I had a redirect plugin. But I have disabled it now.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the permalinks settings. Hope your issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with another browser, 301 is a permanent redirection and it can be difficult to get rid of it. In firefox you have to clear the [network cache](https://superuser.com/a/688240), in the networking settings of firefox.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect this is happening because the WP database still has information on the old `lead` slug that you have deleted.

When you change a slug, the old permalinks are still stored in the database which can cause issues if you want to reuse that name.

1. **Check your Trash**: 
   Make sure that the post/page/category/whatever has been deleted and is not sitting in your trash - if a post is still in trash, WP still treats the slug as in use. 
    
   **After it has been deleted *permanently* from trash**:
2. **Flush your Rewrite Cache:** 
   There are [Three Ways to Flush the Rewrite Cache in WordPress](https://www.webhostinghero.com/3-ways-to-flush-the-rewrite-cache-in-wordpress/):

   - re-save your permalinks in the Admin
   - call `flush_rewrite_rules();` in your functions.php (only add it *temporarily* - you don't want it to run all the time).
   - delete the cache from the database: Run the following query in the database: 
     `SELECT * FROM  wp_options WHERE  option_name = 'rewrite_rules'`
     You should only get 1 result - edit it to remove the `option_value`. See [Three Ways...](https://www.webhostinghero.com/3-ways-to-flush-the-rewrite-cache-in-wordpress/) for more info.
3. **Clear your Browser Cache & Caching plugins**
   Note: some security plugins also use caching e.g. Securi, so check those too.
4. **Delete old WP permalinks**
   If its still not working, run this query in your database to clear all the old slugs from the `postmeta` table:

   `DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug';`

    
   *Ref ['Remove Old Permalinks?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409265/remove-old-permalinks#answer-37958123)*
    
   **Note**: Back up your database before you make any changes in there directly - any mistakes could break your site.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. I didn't know about number 4. I thought all permalinks were connected to the guid or postname field in wp_posts. I tried everything else. The project has been taken away from me now. I think the redirection was caused by another service in their system. I deleted the Wordpress directory but it was still redirecting. So clearly not a Wordpress problem.