# Wordpress - Can't rename blog post link / Where can I find the URLs of my blog posts in the database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a blog post where I want to change the link, but it doesn't work.

I want to rename it in something like "postname" but it always adds something to it, like "postname-2". I have cleared my trash, but that didn't help either.

My next step was to look into the database.

I searched under wp_posts and typed in the url, but I didn't find anything. It seems like no blog posts are stored in wp_posts - where are they stored?

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache and refresh your rewrite rules? See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956198/wordpress-new-page-redirects-to-old-404-page/46010851#46010851

Comment: Nevermind, another page had that url for some reason. But however, why didn't I find this in wp_posts? Are blog posts stored in another table?