# Wordpress Page URL Slug

Tags: sql, wordpress

Hi have the page 2825 with url slug 2825-2 and i cant change for 2815(only) how i can change?

Comment: you may have the same slug in trash delete it permanently an will be okay

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reasons this could be happening, not just because you already have a post or page with this slug:

1. **Check your Trash**: 
   Make sure that all posts/pages/categories/etc have been deleted and are not sitting in your trash - if a post is still in trash, WP still treats the slug as in use.
    
   You could use a plugin such as [Bulk Delete](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/) to easily delete all trash.

**After it has been deleted *permanently* from trash**:

2. **Flush your Rewrite Cache:** 
   There are [Three Ways to Flush the Rewrite Cache in WordPress](https://www.webhostinghero.com/3-ways-to-flush-the-rewrite-cache-in-wordpress/):

   - re-save your permalinks in the Admin
   - call `flush_rewrite_rules();` in your functions.php (only add it *temporarily* - you don't want it to run all the time).
   - delete the cache from the database: Run the following query in the database: 
     `SELECT * FROM  wp_options WHERE  option_name = 'rewrite_rules'`
     You should only get 1 result - edit it to remove the `option_value`. See [Three Ways...](https://www.webhostinghero.com/3-ways-to-flush-the-rewrite-cache-in-wordpress/) for more info.
3. **Delete old WP permalinks**
   If its still not working, run this query in your database to clear all the old slugs from the `postmeta` table:

   `DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_old_slug';`

    
   *Ref ['Remove Old Permalinks?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409265/remove-old-permalinks#answer-37958123)*

**Note**: Back up your database before you make any changes in there directly - any mistakes could break your site.

Comment: @GonçaloLoureiro Every single step, in that order - including checking the trash of *every* page/post/custom post type and all 3 steps to flush your rewrite cache? And you don't have any caching plugins enabled? I'd be surprised if its not caused by one of the reasons above, because there are very few other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the URL to just be /2815 because there already exists a page, post, or category with the slug. That is why it added the '-2' to the end of the URL.

I would find that page and either update or delete it, then change the URL with the -2 to just be 2815 instead of edit it from the backend to cause a conflict with the existing page, post, or category

Comment: Try typing your url and with the /2815 and see where it takes you. Once there you can update or delete it

Comment: Then check the trash. Might be in there.

Answer (score 0):

The post ID is an auto incremented primary key in the database so you will not be able to roll it back.

Your best bet might be to look into a different permalink structure.